# Object becoming transparent and overlapping itself

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I found another question with a similar issue but it wasn't answered and was abandoned in 2016.

I'm building an augmented reality app with meshes I have reconstructed from real world objects. When testing on a fresh new project I have no problems whatsoever.

Bulbassaur working fine on Android.

[image]

The object I'm using does have a bit of transparency on its material but that's a reconstruction issue; it doesn't bother me for now.

But when I import the object to a different project, trying to use exactly the same settings, the transparency issue appears when it is built on Android.

Bulbassaur with overlapping transparency:

[image]

Bulbassaur with overlapping transparency_2:

[image]

However, when I run it inside Unity, I'm having no issues at all.

Bulbassaur just fine:

[image]

I am fairly new to coding in Unity, so I'm not having any success investigating both projects to find what's wrong. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Your "working fine on android" pic doesnt look fine to me, it has transparencies in wrong places and looks just as broken as the others.. it looks like you're missing a material

Comment: it is missing some materials but thats something i can deal with outside unity